# localhost shows index of/ and not the wordpress file for configuration

Tags: server, apache2

I tried the following: Edit the configuration file:

*sudo {editor of choice} 000-default.conf*

**Note: Be sure to replace {editor of choice} with your editor of choice, be it nano, vim, or anything else that can edit text.
Find the DocumentRoot value and edit it accordingly:**

*DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress*

**Save the file
Restart/Reload the Apache configuration files:**

*sudo service apache2 restart*

And when I did that, I get a blank page and nothing. If I change it back to var/www/html then I at least get the Index Of/ page.

This is a brand new install. My assumption from the guide I am following is that this should show, however the configuration page does not come up when I go to localhost, just the index of/ page:

Now, visit http://localhost from your web browser. You should see the WordPress configuration page. Select your language and click on Continue.

I am following this guide:

https://linuxhint.com/wordpress_dev_debian_10/

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. The copy/paste at the start of the question was clearly written by me on a previous answer, and the LinuxHint guide is all about Debian 10, which is not necessarily the same as Ubuntu. Neither of these actually say anything about your server. Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you're running (1) the complete location of the files you want Apache to serve (2) any errors that might be reported in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` (or the site-appropriate log file). With this, it may be possible to identify what's missing from your configuration

Comment: maybe php is not running ? check that first? because apache is clearly working, check if php is running or not using `systemctl`

Comment: Is there a reqson not to follow our ubuntu.com (as you are using Ubuntu and not debian?) https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-wordpress#1-overview

Comment: I could use that tutorial but then I would need to purge and start over. Also, I don't see php specifically listed under systemctl but I do see that apache2 and mariadb are started. I also see that php is installed when I perform a which php and that returns /usr/bin/php so I'm sure that is good. I also don't see any errors in the error log under /var/log/apache2/error.log. Only thing I see is when I do restart the service.

Answer (score 0):

You likely haven't enabled the php module in Apache.

`sudo a2enmod php7.2` (or whatever version of php you have installed)

Alternatively you can use `sudo a2enmod` interactively, and it will list out the modules you can enable.

Then reload the apache config

`sudo service apache2 reload`

Comment: I did this and ran into an mpm error. I fixed that error and then was able to run the sudo a2enmod php8.5. I then restarted apache2 service without any issues. I am still seeing the same Index Of/ website under localhost.  This is really strange